# Automatic deployment from TFS fails with: The process cannot access ..\PrecompiledApp.config' because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, tfs, msbuild, webdeploy, tfsbuild

I have an ASP.NET WebApplication project. We have TFS build definition to do an auto deploy to our test server.

I occasionally get this error when I kick in a build:

> The process cannot access '`..\PrecompiledApp.config`' because it is
>   being used by another process.

I am sure build service is not able to delete that file.

Any idea why would this happen and how do I to stop this happening?

Comment: Is anti-virus configured on your build server? It may lock the files during build.

Comment: @jessehouwing Not sure...but when I recycle the App pool the build goes through. Wonder by IIS would lock it as I have all my builds set to Delete files before auto deploy on our test servers and none complains.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @MarkC. Nope...I just restart app pool or go to the server and delete the file.